# Trailing Edge with Cavity

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

**Question 5:**

I have noticed from PAPER "NASA Supercritical Airfoils - Technical Paper 2969" that they mentioned something called "**Cavity**" merged with the trailing edge.

[image]
Although there is no more detail on it of how it works (Coanda effect or winglet effect) but from experimental tests it shows that it has low drag coefficient compared to blunt TE as we see in below graph.

*

> **So, my question is why we dont see such design in any recent planes ??**

- 

[image]